# Reuse test resources (logback-test.xml) from dependent project with SBT

Tags: sbt, slf4j, logback

I've got 3 project defined in my Build.scala file:

- common
- services.dependsOn(common)
- web.dependsOn(common)

Project Common contains */test/resources* with logback-test.xml configuration which I would like to use for services and web tests.

This setup works fine in **intelliJ** with `sbt-idea` but when I try to run 'sbt test' from command line the logback-test.xml isn't copied over to */services/target/testClasses* or */web/target/testClasses* which means that the tests will use default **slf4j** configuration with useless tons of DEBUG info.

What should I do to force sbt to copy test resources from dependent project to others.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies don't include test configuration by default. You can change this like so:

- `common`
- `services.dependsOn(common % "compile->compile;test->test")`
- `web.dependsOn(common % "compile->compile;test->test")`

More info [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Per-configuration+classpath+dependencies)

Comment: Also be aware: sbt put compile dependencies class paths first and test dependencies class paths -- later. So e.g. you log4j.properties would work in current test/resources, but would be overridden by src/resources for depended modules.